# In which library are the functions declared in winsock.h?

Tags: c

Well I was browsing in the library of `winsock.h` looking for functions but I found nothing besides declarations.
I was just looking for the inet_addr function to see your block how it works

**Ahh! and you must be thinking this crazy does not know that WSAStartup start the winsock DLL ... yes, but does that mean that the functions are there?**

Comment: Header files, in c, should 'never' contain code.  The header files are NOT libraries,  Rather they define the 'interface' to the functions in the related libraries

Answer (score 2):

The functions reside in the ws2_32.dll . If you look at the documentation for these functions, e.g. [WSAStartup](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winsock/nf-winsock-wsastartup) in the "Requirments" section, it will tell you you need to link to the ws2_32.lib file and the ws2_32.dll file is also required.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see *how it works*, you are up a creek with Winsock; the source code is not available.  You can disassemble `ws2_32.dll` but that's tedious and makes it very hard to tell what behavior is contractual and what is accidental.

Instead, I recommend you read through the equivalent functions in an open-source C library; for instance, here is [`inet_addr` in FreeBSD libc](https://svnweb.freebsd.org/base/head/lib/libc/inet/inet_addr.c?view=markup) and [`inet_addr` in GNU libc](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=resolv/inet_addr.c;hb=HEAD).  This will not educate you about Windows-specific quirks; the best sources for those are [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/windows/desktop/ms738563(v=vs.85).aspx) and paper books like *Windows Internals*.